# Create View with an additional generated column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

In my postgres project I have a table `users` and I want to create a view with only the `user_fname`, `user_lname` and `user_points` ordered by `user_points` but I also want to create the view with a generated column with the users positions, like a leaderboard.

This is what I tried to do, it will explain better:

```
create view leaderboard as
select 
position int generated always as identity,
user_fname, 
user_lname,
points
from users
order by points desc
```

Obviously this didn't work, because I'm trying to create the column there, but how can I do something like this?

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to include an `ORDER BY` in a view definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically you want to `RANK` people based on `points`

If I recreate and populate the `users` table with

```
create table users 
(
user_fname varchar, 
user_lname varchar,
points int
);

insert into users values ('Carlo','Rossi',33);
insert into users values ('Mario','Bianchi',35);
insert into users values ('Giorgia','Verdi',35);
insert into users values ('Maria','Blu',37);
```

The `leaderboard` can be created with

```
create or replace view leaderboard as
select 
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY POINTS DESC) as position,
user_fname, 
user_lname,
points
from users
order by points desc;
```

That will provide

```
defaultdb=> select * from leaderboard order by position;
 position | user_fname | user_lname | points 
----------+------------+------------+--------
        1 | Maria      | Blu        |     37
        2 | Mario      | Bianchi    |     35
        2 | Giorgia    | Verdi      |     35
        4 | Carlo      | Rossi      |     33
(4 rows)
```

Note that `Mario Bianchi` and `Giorgia Verdi` are both at the 2nd position since they share the same `35 points`